# Java Keytool and C#

Tags: c#, java, keytool

I'm trying to make a program in C# to run an automatic key tool and generate a key for Android development but I have some problems that I can't figure out.

Code in C#:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = 
    new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.FileName = 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) 
    + "\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_40\\bin\\keytool.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = 
    "-exportcert -alias androidkey -keystore d:\\debug.keystore > C:\\asd.txt";

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

On the command line it tells me this:

```
Illegal option: >keytool -exportcert [OPTION] ...
```

And I tried to run the exact command in the key tool manually and there was no problem.

Comment: the right way it shows is -> 
Illegal Option: >
keytool -exportcert [OPTION]...

Comment: Output redirection over `>` is a feature of the shell (e.g. `cmd.exe`), not of the operating system. It's possible that `System.Diagnostics.Process` doesn't support it.

Comment: And is there a way i can use the > in a way ascii code or something?

Comment: You could redirect the process' standard output, read it into a string, and write it into the target file from the C# program: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx.

Comment: I've tried that but no success, i'm thinking to do a more quick get away mode to write in a file and save it in .cmd and run it, but that's not exactly automatic. 

Or is there other way to save the key that is generated from keytool into a file except with the >

Comment: Why "no success". I guess I forgot to mention, when redirecting the output that way, you need to leave out the `>` and everything after it from `Arguments`.

Comment: I found a fix, i checked all the types of the commands and in exchange of > i used -file (how obvious...) and now everthing works good.

@millimoose i will use what you told me. Thank you !